# Filter ElasticSearch results based on AND condition in an array

Tags: database, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Below is the data sample of a single record in my Index:

```
{
        "_index" : "test_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "49605102905391763685971719283371021096086998966740189186",
        "_score" : 2.8858113,
        "_source" : {
          "properties" : {
            "activity" : [
              {
                "activityId" : 39,
                "actionVersion" : 2,
                "actionIdx" : 3
              },
              {
                "activityId" : 39,
                "actionVersion" : 2,
                "actionIdx" : 4
              },
              {
                "activityId" : 39,
                "actionVersion" : 2,
                "actionIdx" : 5
              },
              {
                "activityId" : 42,
                "actionVersion" : 2,
                "actionIdx" : 3
              },
              {
                "activityId" : 42,
                "actionVersion" : 2,
                "actionIdx" : 4
              },
              {
                "activityId" : 42,
                "actionVersion" : 2,
                "actionIdx" : 5
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
```

I want to filter results based on activitiyId 42 and actionIdx 3. I'm using below query trying to get results.

```
{"size":-1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
            "should": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "activityId": 42
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "actionIdx": 3
                            }
                        }
                        
                        
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
  }
}
```

I'm getting the records that contain activityid 42 and actionidx 3 but my requirement is to have records that contain activity 42 and actionidx 3 in the same object. Below are my results with above search query:

```
      "activity" : [
              {
                "activityId" : 39,
                "actionVersion" : 2,
                "actionIdx" : 2
              },
              {
                "activityId" : 28,
                "actionVersion" : 2,
                "actionIdx" : 3
              },
              {
                "activityId" : 42,
                "actionVersion" : 2,
                "actionIdx" : 2
              },
              {
                "activityId" : 41,
                "actionVersion" : 2,
                "actionIdx" : 3
              }
            ]
```

My expected output to be:

```
"activity" : [
              {
                "activityId" : 39,
                "actionVersion" : 2,
                "actionIdx" : 2
              },
              {
                "activityId" : 28,
                "actionVersion" : 2,
                "actionIdx" : 3
              },
              {
                "activityId" : 42,
                "actionVersion" : 2,
                "actionIdx" : 3
              }
            ]
```

Here's is the mapping index. Activity is not nested

```
"properties" : {
            "properties" : {
              "activity" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "actionIdx" : {
                    "type" : "long"
                  },
                  "actionVersion" : {
                    "type" : "long"
                  },
                  "activityId" : {
                    "type" : "long"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
```

Comment: Can u provide your index mapping ? I am working on your search query and will provide a working example

Comment: Hi @OpsterElasticsearchNinja, I've tried creating a new Index with nested type object, but still I'm facing the issue of not getting results.

Comment: I hv given complete example of nested type, did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use [nested data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) and query to achieve that, right now as you are not using it, its considered as object data type(default) and nested documents clearly mention the issue you are facing.

> When ingesting key-value pairs with a large, arbitrary set of keys,
> you might consider modeling each key-value pair as its own nested
> document with key and value fields. Instead, consider using the
> flattened data type, which maps an entire object as a single field and
> allows for simple searches over its contents. Nested documents and
> queries are typically expensive, so using the flattened data type for
> this use case is a better option.

**Index Mapping**

```
    {
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "properties": {
        "properties": {
          "activity": {
            "type": "nested"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "properties": {
        "activity": [
            {
                "activityId": 39,
                "actionVersion": 2,
                "actionIdx": 3
            },
            {
                "activityId": 39,
                "actionVersion": 2,
                "actionIdx": 4
            },
            {
                "activityId": 39,
                "actionVersion": 2,
                "actionIdx": 5
            },
            {
                "activityId": 42,
                "actionVersion": 2,
                "actionIdx": 3
            },
            {
                "activityId": 42,
                "actionVersion": 2,
                "actionIdx": 4
            },
            {
                "activityId": 42,
                "actionVersion": 2,
                "actionIdx": 5
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "properties.activity",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "properties.activity.activityId": 42
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "properties.activity.actionIdx": 3
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits":{}
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result**

```
 "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "fd_cb1",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "properties.activity",
                    "offset": 3
                  },
                  "_score": 2.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "activityId": 42,
                    "actionVersion": 2,
                    "actionIdx": 3
                  }
                }
              ]
```

Comment: Hi I've tried the query but still it ain't working. Also the mapping for activity isn't nested.